# How to use GraphRequestBatch on android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm retrieving the posts of a public page like this:

```
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/DrumTalkTV/posts", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.e(TAG,response.toString());
                    try {
                        imgProfile = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/DrumTalkTV/picture?width=150&height=150");
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent feed = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Feed.class);
                    feed.putExtra("respuesta",response.getJSONObject().toString());
                    feed.putExtra("imgProfile",imgProfile.toString());
                    startActivity(feed);
                }
            }
    );
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,story,message,object_id, properties,source,created_time");
    parameters.putString("locale","es_ES");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

This code works fine but now I want to retrieve posts from several pages but I dont know how to do it I'm trying something like this:

```
    GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/Google/posts", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.e(TAG,response.toString());
                            try {
                                imgProfile = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/Google/picture?width=150&height=150");
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ),
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/DrumTalkTV/posts", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.e(TAG,response.toString());
                            try {
                                imgProfile = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/DrumTalkTV/picture?width=150&height=150");
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ));
    batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {

            Intent feed = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Feed.class);
            feed.putExtra("respuesta",graphRequests.toString());
            feed.putExtra("imgProfile",imgProfile.toString());
            startActivity(feed);
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,story,message,object_id, properties,source,created_time");
    parameters.putString("locale","es_ES");
    // since=2011-01-01 until=2011-05-05
    batch.setParameters(parameters);
    batch.executeAsync();
```

But I can't even compile `batch.setParameters(parameters);`

I'm not sure how that method works but what I want is to retrieve a mix of post from several public pages ordered by date.

Comment: This does not necessarily need batch requests, you can do one request of the form `?ids=page_1,page_2,...&fields=feed` This will get you the posts in an individual sub-structure for each page, so mixing them together in chronological order is something you’ll have to do on your end.

Comment: If I use  `new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "?ids=Google,DrumTalkTV&fields=posts", null...`, I get `errorMessage: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (message) on node type (Page)`

Comment: The request itself works, see [example in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3DGoogle%2CDrumTalkTV%26fields%3Dposts&version=v2.12). Try leaving the path blank (if that’s possible with your SDK), and specify the `ids` the same way as `fields` is specified.

Comment: Thanks I think I have something: I let my path as "/posts" (blank is not possible) and Specified ids later. But now how can I get the page profile image for every page? I was using `imgProfile = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/DrumTalkTV/picture?width=150&height=150");`in `onCompleted()` method

Comment: Just request the picture field directly with the same request …? `fields=posts,picture`

Comment: But my `fields`variable are for posts' fields. If I put `picture` here it wil retrieve pictures of the post, not the profile picture.

Comment: Ah ok, that’s because you are already requesting /posts, and you can not “go up one level” from there using `fields`. Have you tried if you can specify the path as just `/`, and then use `fields=posts,picture` ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165958/discussion-between-juan-lopez-and-cbroe).